# MockMvc ignores JsonFormat jackson annotation

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, spring-hateoas

I set-up a REST API with Spring MVC and Spring HATEOAS. 
In one of the DTOs I put a JsonFormat on a ZonedDateTime field.

Running the server gives me the expected date format (yyyyMMdd), but with testing the annotation is ignored and I get something like 1454281200.000000000. So it looks like when testing the annotation is ignored totally. I tried the @JsonIgnore annotation, but that on was working.

No matter I use MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build() or MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(membersController).build() the time is simply not converted to the JsonFormat as expected.

Anyone any idea's what going wrong here? I expect some configuration issue, but I don't know where to look at.

Discovered that the aDate on the Resource is serialised properly, but the xxxDTO.aDate is not serialised properly.

Resource

```
public class XxxResource extends Resource<XxxDTO> {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyyMMdd")
    private ZonedDateTime aDate;

    public XxxResource(XxxDTO xxxDTO) {
        super(xxxDTO);
        this.aDate = xxxDTO.getADate();
    }
}
```

DTO

```
public class XxxDTO {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyyMMdd")
    private ZonedDateTime aDate;
}
```

pom.xml

```
    <jackson.version>2.8.3</jackson.version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Test setup

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {
   XxxController xxxController = new XxxController(XxxService, new XxxResourceAssembler(),
            new PagedResourcesAssembler<>(new HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(), null));
   this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(xxxController).setCustomArgumentResolvers
            (new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver()).build();
}
```

The endpoints are set up through a web.xml and the WebMvcConfig is like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
   argumentResolvers.add(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }

    @Bean
    public PagedResourcesAssembler pagedResourcesAssembler() {
    return new PagedResourcesAssembler(new HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(), null);
    }
}
```